# Mutiselect Dropdown not showing List using bootstrap-multiselect.min.js

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Multi-select Drop-down inside table head when opened, drop-down list has no value. below is the code, plz suggest any bootstrap class needs to be added .... i need to apply filter on this drop-down value using angularjs

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
 $('#filterName').multiselect();
   $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_mysql.php")
   .then(function (response) {
  $scope.names = response.data.records;
   });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
 
<table class="table table-stripped">
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>
   <select id="filterName" multiple="multiple">
    <option ng-repeat="x in names">{{ x.Name }}</option>
   </select>
  </th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to execute `multiselect()` with delay.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_mysql.php")
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.names = response.data.records;
    });
});

setTimeout(function() { 
  $('#filterName').multiselect();
}, 300);
```

Comment: any specific reason

Comment: You have to fetch data first and then run the multiselect. In your code you run `multiselect()` before getting the data and that is why you don't have any names in your select.

Comment: thanks for the help ... you seem to be good in Bootstrap .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37531152/bootstrap-columns-reordering-issues

Comment: Just curious, is the 300 delay more than enough, or is it depends on the connection? This solution do solve my problem, but I'm curious if this solution will fail if the connection is so poor. Is there any solution involving .then or any else solution?