# Bootstrap: img-responsive vs img-fluid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-images

I am using bootstrap 3.3.6 and I am using class `img-responsive` for image responsiveness.

I have found a new class name `img-fluid`, but it's not present in 3.3.6 version.

Can anyone tell what is the difference between `img-responsive` and `img-fluid`?

`img-responsive` just resizes the image as per parent container size which we can achive it using css property `width: 100%` and `height: auto`. Then why to use `image-responsive` class?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`img-responsive` was in Bootstrap 3, `img-fluid` is in Bootstrap 4 since beta version.

> Removes display: block; from .img-fluid. Responsive image behavior is not dependent on display: block;, so we can safely remove it on our end. Should you need block level, you can easily override that in the source or with a utility class.

```
.img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: img-responsive just resize the image as per parent container size which we can achive it using css property width: 100% and height: auto. then why to use imag-responsive class

Comment: They use `max-width` property, not `width`. If you have `width: 100%` your image will not be responsive.

Comment: thanks can you plz help me with this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541402/mutiselect-dropdown-not-showing-list-using-bootstrap-multiselect-min-js

Comment: I don't know Angular.

Comment: In Internet Explorer 9-10, SVG images with .img-fluid are disproportionately sized. To fix this, add width: 100% \9; where necessary. This fix improperly sizes other image formats, so Bootstrap doesn’t apply it automatically.

Comment: its a bootstrap multi select dropdown issue

Comment: Where does the quote in your answer come from? From what I understand, `display: block` has always been a part of the CSS in both Bootstrap 3 and 4.

Comment: I don't remember where it came from. Since Bootstrap 4 beta there is no `display: block` in `img-fluid`.

Comment: There is another quote on https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2016/10/19/bootstrap-4-alpha-5/. `Removed the display: block; from .img-fluid as it’s unnecessary for creating responsive images (the inline-block default works great as-is).`